# Using the expand() function in snakemake to perform a shell command multiple times

Tags: snakemake

I would like to perform an R script multiple times on different input files with the help of snakemake. To do this I tried the use of the expand function.

I am relatively new to snakemake and when I understand it correctly, the expand function gives me for example multiple input files which are then all concatenated and available via `{input}`.

Is it possible to call the shell command on the files one by one?

Lets say I have this definition in my config.yaml:

```
types:
    - "A"
    - "B"
```

This would be my example rule:

```
rule manual_groups:
    input:
        expand("chip_{type}.bed",type=config["types"])
    output:
        expand("data/p_chip_{type}.model",type=config["types"])
    shell:
        "Rscript scripts/pre_process.R {input}"
```

This would lead to the command:

```
Rscript scripts/pre_process.R chip_A.bed chip_B.bed
```

Is it possible to instead call the command two times independently with two types like this:

```
Rscript scripts/pre_process.R chip_A.bed
Rscript scripts/pre_process.R chip_B.bed
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define [final target files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) in `rule all`, and then just use appropriate wildcard (i.e., `type`) in rule `manual_groups`. This would run `rule manual_groups` separately for each output file listed in `rule all`.

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/p_chip_{type}.model",type=config["types"])


rule manual_groups:
    input:
        "chip_{type}.bed"
    output:
        "data/p_chip_{type}.model"
    shell:
        "Rscript scripts/pre_process.R {input}"
```

PS- You may want to change wildcard term `type` because of potential conflict with Python's [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) method.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I did not know that you can define the type wildcard in another part than the rule itself.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with the answer of @ManavalanGajapathy that this is the most reliable solution for *your* problem. This however is not a full answer.

The `expand` is just a regular Python function defined in Snakemake. That means that you can use it everywhere when you can use Python. It is just an utility that takes a string and parameters for substitution, and returns the list of strings where each string is a result of a single substitution. This utility can be handy in many places. Below I'm providing a fancy example that illustrates the idea. Let's imagine that you need to take a text file as an input and substitute some characters (the list should be provided from config). Let's imagine that you know the only way to do it: as a pipeline of `sed` scripts. Like that:

```
cat input.txt | sed 's/A/a/g' | sed 's/B/b/g' | sed 's/C/c/g' > output.txt
```

You come to the conclusion that you need to pipeline a chain of sed commands that differ in two symbols: sed 's/**X**/**x**/g'. Here is a solution using the `expand` function:

```
rule substitute:
    input: "input.txt"
    output: "output.txt"
    params:
       from = ["A", "B", "C"],
       to = ["a", "b", "c"]
    shell: "cat {input} | " + " | ".join(expand("sed 's/{from}/{to}/g'", zip, from=params.from, to=params.to)) + " > {output}"
```